# Target Webpack bundled TypeScript functionality from plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have not found a way to reference TypeScript code that is bundled/minified using Webpack from plain JavaScript code.
In my situation, it does not make sense to throw this plain JS "client" code into the Webpack bundling scheme.  The client and server code need to remain separate.
This all runs in the Browser.
I hacked my way through this by creating several "wrapper functions" inside the bundle, that are put onto the global window object (so no imports have to be done to reference them)
The plain JS client code then calls these wrapper functions that then call other TypeScript code.
But this is not a scalable approach.

Comment: There might be some confusion. There shouldn't be any TypeScript function after webpack. It should all be Javascript. Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: You should be able to configure webpack to export your library/module entry point(s) to a global item, [output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget)